# Unique grunt globbing issue

Tags: css, gruntjs, animate.css, glob

Animate.css is an amazing library that I'm pulling into my project via bower (can't change the folder name). Unfortunately, the folder's name is "animate.css". I want to glob in my whole project (including bower_components) for `/**.*.css`. Unfortunately, grunt gets angry because `animate.css` is a folder, not a file. I need a way to ignore the folder, but not the file. Any tips?

Here's what my task looks like now:

```
cssmin: {
  deploy: {
    files: {
      '<%= config.prod %>/styles.min.css': ['<%= config.copy %>/**/*.css', '!**/animate.css/']
    }
  }
}
```

I have [an issue](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/237) on the project. Feel free to respond there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [supply a filter property to the files object to filter out directories](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files):

```
cssmin: {
  deploy: {
    files: [
      {
        src: ['<%= config.copy %>/**/*.css'],
        dest: '<%= config.prod %>/styles.min.css',
        filter: 'isFile'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Learned that from every libraries' Gruntfile.js, thank you for the reminder!