# Grunt is treating folder with a dot as a file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, glob, animate.css

When trying to compile my grunt file and build into my `dist` folder for deployment I get the following error in the console:

```
Running "rev:dist" (rev) task
dist/public/app/app.js >> 63decaf3.app.js
dist/public/app/vendor.js >> a09756ab.vendor.js
dist/public/app/app.css >> d2017fc8.app.css
Warning: Unable to read "dist/public/bower_components/animate.css" file (Error code: EISDIR).
```

The reason for this is that I have a bower component I've got installed named [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css).  This library is of course installed in my `bower_components` folder, but the matching string I have in my Grunt file only looks for files with an extension of `.js`, `.css`, et cetera.  Here's my matching string:

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',  // Offending line
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the directory structure:

```
bower_components
  -> ...
  -> angular-ui-router
  -> animate.css  // Folder with the error
  ---> animate.css  // File that it should be recognizing
  ---> animate.min.css  // File that it should be recognizing
  -> es5-shim
  -> ...
```

In this case, how would I tell Grunt that this is a directory which contains files rather than a file itself?

Comment: Why are you using `{,*/}`?  If I'm reading the docs right, that matches either an empty string or a directory name (including the trailing slash).  Looks to me like you should be using `**/*.css`.  (By the way, globs and regexes are not the same thing.)

Comment: You're right about the difference between globs and regex, I've edited the tags of my post accordingly.  The reason I use `{,*/}` instead is because that will rename only the final concatenated files (since everything is combined into one large `.js` and one large `.css` file.  Doing `**/*.css` renames all the css files, not just the few files I need.  Does that make sense or should I reexplain?

Comment: I ran into this issue before - the culprit was that I used a version of grunt-devcode that didn't properly deal with dots in directories - the point at which you're getting the error is after your html has been "simplified" - so maybe another npm package is not dealing with the dots properly. Not sure if you are using grunt-devcode but I would start by talking a look at the packages you use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have slightly different approach.

`bower install animate-css --save`

it will grab animate.css but save at:

`bower_components/animate-css`

Using this method you don't have to play with Gruntfile.js which I personally consider unpleasant to edit and even look at ;)

Comment: Is this hyphenation of the package name specific to the animate.css library or is that something bower does when people submit packages with dots in the name?

Comment: There is nothing in bower.json of animate.css project indicating alternative name. I am guessing its Bower's fallback method. If I would be you I would do quick experiment by installing other package - I am guessing you are still seriously intrigued to do so :>

Comment: This does not work with bower packages like fullpage.js. Throws an error " ENOTFOUND Package fullpage-js not found"

Answer (score 6):

Exclude the `animate.css` folder, then include everything inside it. I am not sure about the exact glob options [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12633119/3995789), for details. Something like this:

```
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/animate.css',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/bower_components/animate.css/animate.css',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see someone make this into a more general glob too... I could see issues arising if you had a folder called `awesomeLib.js` which is a common naming scheme of projects.

Comment: @cereallarceny I think no one should name their folders like that, it's dangerous, you can't workaround for every configuration you have.

Comment: I agree, but it really isn't up to me what other people do.

Comment: Upvoting because this works and the solution marked as correct above does NOT

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a [custom filter function](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function) with the [fs.Stats](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats:) method. Also, there is the `ext` option ( Indicates where the period demarcating the extension is located. )

**ext: [String](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file)**

```
src: [
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',  // Offending line
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
     ],
     filter: 'isDirectory',
```

You may need to use `isFile` depending on if you only want to match actual files instead.

Comment: I don't believe this works.  It throws an error:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/octovis/barnacle/Gruntfile.js:218
            filter: 'isDirectory',
                  ^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.

Comment: By the way, changing it to filter: 'isFile' throws the same error.

Comment: Try it the way I've shown now. I think you'll want to use `isFile` though.

Comment: Weird, I changed it to your latest edit and tried both `isDirectory` and `isFile` and both of them gave me the exact same error as in my OP.

Comment: Interesting. It maybe an issue where the regex isn't traversing into the directory... the only other thing I can suggest atm is `/public/{,**/}*.css`

Comment: @cereallarceny, Oh one more thing I just thought of `dot: true`. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Shame, neither the `/public/{,**/}*.css` string nor adding the `dot: true` with the `isFile` or `isDirectory` filter works. Completely bizarre...

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning to write `ext`: — although i've never tried it. Apparently you can indicate the period where the actual extension is located, so maybe that could help.

Comment: Really though, the filter should've worked - so I'm a bit baffled. There are quite a few other file options listed on the docs that I linked, maybe browse there for a bit.

Comment: The filter is not responsible for triggering a SyntaxError in your Gruntfile. Is you code Javascript-ok ? Does jshint likes it ?

Comment: JS hint does indeed like it.

Comment: `isFile` should work fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503077/unique-grunt-globbing-issue/24503596#24503596

Answer (score 0):

Example of isFile usage, worked a charm for me.

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.js',
      '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/local.js',
      '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/web.js',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ],
    filter: 'isFile'
  }
},
```